# Angular4: Injecting parent component in the constructor - making it fails safe

Tags: angular

Somewhere on the web I saw a tutorial about creating a tab component in it used this awesomely simple pattern

// TABS COMPONENT

```
export class TabsComponent{
    tabs: TabItemComponent[];

    addTab(tab: TabItemComponent){
        this.tabs.push(tab);
    }
}
```

// TAB ITEM COMPONENT

```
export class TabItemComponent{
    constructor(private tabsComponent: TabsComponent){
        this.tabsComponent.addTab(this);
    }
}
```

// VIEW

```
<tabs>
    <tab-item>text 1</tab-item>
    <tab-item>Text 2</tab-item>
</tabs>
```

Really cool and clean pattern to get the parent injected into the child

now, this works fine when the parent is actually there in the view... so perfect for tabs...

a little less perfect for ButtonGroupComponent and ButtonComponent scenario, where Button can be standalone and not necessarily wrapped in the Button Group

I have similar pattern there with an exception

```
constructor(private buttonGroup: ButtonGroupComponent) {
  if (this.buttonGroup) {
    this.buttonGroup.addButton(this);
  }
}
```

But, if the button is standalone this does not work, I get an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for
>   ButtonGroupComponent!

Any ideas how to prevent the error in the constructor?

Comment: Have you tried decorating the argument with `@Optional()`? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Optional-decorator.html

Comment: You are the man! thanks! You can post it as answer! CHEERS! Was not aware of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decorate the argument with `@Optional()`. See [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Optional-decorator.html).